# Who drop Secure Cookie in PHP with apache2 in HTTP?

Tags: php, apache2, insomnia

I am learning session and cookie configuration of php.

I set up a php running in apache2 server in my localhost.

I try to use a tool `insomnia` to send a GET request to the end point(`http://localhost:8000/test.php`) with the script below.

```php
<?php

session_start(['cookie_secure' => true]);

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    exit($_SESSION['token']);
}

$_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

exit;
```

After the first request, I manage to get the `session cookie` and set the `$_SESSION['token']`.

When I send the second request, I did not manage to receive the `token`. The reason is the `session cookie` is not received by the php.

My question is who actually discard the cookie in the second request? `insomnia` or `php` or `apahce2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insomnia would have dropped it because you flagged the cookie as secure then used HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks. I manage to verify it by using a browser to send a request to the endpoint and the php did receive the secure Cookie in the second request. So, it means neither `php` nor `apache2` discard the cookie. `PS: browser didn't drop secure cookie from localhost`